# Consolidate dictionary based on repeat values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary set up like this

```
{
     "key1" : [1,2,4],
     "key2" : [2,4],
     "key3" : [1,2,4],
     "key4" : [2,4],
     ....
}
```

What I want is something like this.

```
[
  [ 
     ["key1", "key3"],
     [1,2,4],
  ],
  [ 
     ["key2", "key4"],
     [2,4],
  ],
  .....
]
```

A list of keys and values based on unique value pairs. How can I do this in a pythonic way?

Answer (score 5):

You can invert the dictionnary like this :

```
orig = {
     "key1" : [1,2,4],
     "key2" : [2,4],
     "key3" : [1,2,4],
     "key4" : [2,4],
}

new_dict = {}

for k, v in orig.iteritems():
    new_dict.setdefault(tuple(v), []).append(k)    #need to "freeze" the mutable type into an immutable to allow it to become a dictionnary key (hashable object)

# Here we have new_dict like this :
#new_dict = {
#    (2, 4): ['key2', 'key4'],
#    (1, 2, 4): ['key3', 'key1']
#}

# like sverre suggested :
final_output = [[k,v] for k,v in new_dict.iteritems()]
```

Comment: Note that to get from here to the structure OP specified is simply `[[k,v] for k,v in new_dict.iteritems()]`

Comment: @Ignacio, sverre : thanks, I edited my answer with your propoistions

Comment: @sverre Actually to get what the OP requested you need slightly different: `[[k,list(v)] for v,k in new_dict.iteritems()]` i.e. switch k and v around. Also `iteritems()` doesn't exist in Python 3, use `items()` if you want the code snippet to work in both (the OP didn't say which).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list comprehension to do the job cleanly:

```
[[[key for key in dictionary.keys() if dictionary[key] == value], value]
   for value in unique(list(dictionary.values()))]
```

Where `unique` can be a function that returns the unique elements of a list. There is no default for this, but there are many implementations ([here are some](http://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1SNNT_enUS418US418&sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&rlz=1C1SNNT_enUS418US418&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=python%20unique%20elements%20in%20list&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=8b5a7a9984220ba2&ion=1&biw=1366&bih=667)).

Answer (score 0):

Please find my sample code below if it is still actual for you:

```
orig = {
     "key1" : [1,2,4],
     "key2" : [2,4],
     "key3" : [1,2,4],
     "key4" : [2,4],
}

unique = map(list, set(map(tuple, orig.values())))
print map(lambda val: [val, filter(lambda key: orig[key] == val, orig)], unique)
```